# Change linear interpolation in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have data that looks like this:

```
    sv_length   status  right_edge  left_edge
0   (0.999, 3.0]    0.142857    3.000000e+00    9.990000e-01
1   (3.0, 6.0]  0.125000    6.000000e+00    3.000000e+00
2   (6.0, 11.3] 0.153846    1.130000e+01    6.000000e+00
3   (11.3, 18.375]  0.964286    1.837500e+01    1.130000e+01
4   (18.375, 28.0]  0.965517    2.800000e+01    1.837500e+01
```

When I plot it, as so:

```
sbn.lineplot(x=binned['right_edge'], y=binned['status'])
plt.xlim([1, 100])
plt.xscale("log")
```

I get the following:

[image]

There is clearly linear interpolation between the values in "right_edge" (ie. the slanted edges). How can I make it so that the plot shows right-most interpolation (ie. extending each value to the left until the previous point is reached, thus producing horizontal lines)?

Comment: `plt.step(df['right_edge'], df['status'])`?

Comment: Thanks! Just didn't know the command.